# error C2039: 'chrono': is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++-chrono

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to create Win32 Project. I tried to use chrono library, but it says it cannot find it. I tested the code with chrono library in a console project, but it worked on the console project, but not on Win32 project.

```
#include <chrono>
...
using namespace std::chrono;

LocalDriveHeader header;
auto durnow = system_clock::now ().time_since_epoch ();

header.version = VERSION;
header.flags = 0x0000;
header.sector_size = sector_size;
header.early_time = chrono::duration_cast <milliseconds> (durnow).count ();
...
```

**===EDIT===**

Yes, I did included chrono header.
The project is Win32 Project with precompiled-header.

```
c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(123): error C2039: 'chrono': is not a member of 'std'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1175): note: see declaration of 'std'
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(123): error C2871: 'chrono': a namespace with this name does not exist
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(126): error C2653: 'system_clock': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(126): error C3861: 'now': identifier not found
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(126): error C2228: left of '.time_since_epoch' must have class/struct/union
1>  c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(126): note: type is 'unknown-type'
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(131): error C2653: 'chrono': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(131): error C2065: 'duration_cast': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(131): error C2065: 'milliseconds': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\eunbin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gamgeum\gamgeum\container.cpp(131): error C3536: 'durnow': cannot be used before it is initialized
```

Comment: Have you included the <chrono> header?

Comment: @ChrisStathis Yes.

Comment: Show the complete code and the exact error you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added `#include <chrono>` into the precompiled header.
I have no idea why adding `#include <chrono>` into the actual source caused problem...

Answer (score 7):

You may be lacking a `#include <chrono>` at the top of your file. You need this `#include` in order to have access to the `std::chrono` namespace.

Comment: I did not included the part where I included <chrono>. Yes, I did included chrono, but I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 5):

I just now encountered this myself. In my case, I had newly added a file named "Time.h" to my project, and that caused a name-collision with an internal header included by  in MSVC's STL. Oddly, it manifested in the way you described. Renaming that file fixed it.

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 3):

The issue in my case was that the include statement for "chrono" was before the one for "stdafx.h"

Comment: Yep, you fixed my problem. Now in VS2019 for a CppUnitTest file it's "pch.h" and "CppUnitTest.h". I stupidly put them after <chrono> because I was misapplying Core Guidelines.